# Ruby on Rails redirect I18n

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

According to the Railscasts video Ruby on Rails - Railscasts PRO #138 I18n (revised) to redirect the user going to domain.com/products to the default locale domain.com/en/products I should add to my routes.rb:

```
match '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
match '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")
```

This doesn't work. First I get an error saying I should replace "match" with "get". Then when I do that I get an error from my browser saying ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Any ideas why this isn't working? Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: Please post your complete error log.

Comment: Hi Pavan. I don't know where to look for the errors as the error comes from the browser telling me there aree too many redirects. I get no errors when restarting the server. One indication might be that when going to localhost:3000 it redirects to localhost:3000/sv/sv which isn't right. It should go to localhost:3000/sv. But also when I go to localhost:3000/sv/priser the browser tells me there are too many redirects

Comment: According to the video tutorial. When the user goes to localhost:3000/priser it should redirect them to localhost:3000/sv/priser. When I get it working I still get a redirect to localhost:3000/priser and not localhost:3000/sv/priser

Comment: You should keep in mind that the revised version Railsscasts is from 2012 since them rails haver jumped from version 3.2 to 4.2. Which Rails version are you using?

Comment: yeah, I know... 4.2.2. Spent two days with this now and I guess I haven't learned enough yet to really understand what it is that I need to do to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
get '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}"), constraints: lambda { |req| !req.path.starts_with? "/#{I18n.default_locale}/" }
get '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")
```